# Is it possible to save a wiki template in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: wiki, template, enterprise-wiki

I need to be able to save a wiki for reuse. Ideally I'd like to set up a Enterprise wiki and then save out a template for further use. Is it possible to save an Enterprise Wiki as a template in Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked in to Site Templates, basically you save the site as a template solution that you can base new sites on.

To save as a template:

Navigate to Site Settings ->Under “Site Actions”  select “Save Site as Template”

Read more: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/11/23/how-to-save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013/#ixzz2mQAMmVMq